# "Operation is not valid" when trying to create a List

Tags: sharepoint, list, sharepoint-2010

I want to clone a list in Sharepoint. This is the code:

```
private static void CloneList(SPList sourceList, string targetListName)
{
    SPWeb web = sourceList.ParentWeb;
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

    Guid targetListId;
    targetListId = web.Lists.Add(targetListName, sourceList.Description, sourceList.BaseTemplate);  
   // irrelevant stuff
}
```

On the last code line (Lists.Add()) I get the error

```
operation is not valid due to the current state of the object sharepoint 2010
```

any idea what to do to solve that issue? (running the code with elevatedPrivilegues does not solve the issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
targetListId = web.Lists.Add(targetListName, sourceList.Description, SPListTemplateType.CustomGrid)
```

Greats Hechler